# What Operations in snowflake do not consume compute credits?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I know that DDL and Show operations do not consume compute credits? Is there any list some one has compiled to determine what operations in snowflake do not consume compute credits? Appreciate your help

Comment: As per snowflake documentation there is no such statement that they dont charge for DDL operations.  Snowflake credits are charged for the processing time used by each virtual warehouse. Only the queries that's been taken from cache are not counted for credit points. You can ready more about snowflake pricing here - https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/credits.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard rule that snowflake doesn't charge for DDL and Show operations. They will charge based on the cost of storage and the cost of compute resources consumed.

**Storage:**  storage is per terabyte, compressed, per month and charge for compute is based on the processing units, which we refer to as credits, consumed to run our queries.

please refer following link for more details:
https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/

Comment: Be careful not to mix compute charge with running queries.  The customer pays for warehouses that are up and running, as they are server resources reserved for the customer, even when they are running idle.  It is the customer's responsibility to utilize rented capacity.

Answer (score 0):

There are a list of statements that can be run in Snowflake that do not consume compute (virtual warehouse) credit.  This list can include:
- DDL statements
- Queries that hit result cache
- result_scan query
- Show commands
- Some count, min, max queries.

Snowflake did make an announcement in November that there will be some changes coming starting February 2020 that will include some new Cloud Services billing in some situations for some of these innovative features that were running free of compute credits.  Here's the recently published blog: 
https://www.snowflake.com/blog/whats-new-with-the-snowflake-cloud-services-billing-model/